# How to get oauth token using authorization server endpoint in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

Hi friends i am developing my own oauth2 server having resource server and authorization server configuration i have partially completed my own oauth2 server but unable to get oauth token using token endpoint `http://localhost:8080/oauth/token`.

**OAuthConfig:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;


@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;    

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
                            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("acme")
                    .secret("acmesecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token",
                            "password").scopes("openid");
        }
    }
}
```

**SpringSecurityConfig:**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by qasim on 12/3/16.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(-10)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {




    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated().and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().httpBasic().and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/confirm_access").authenticated();
    }


}
```

In `OauthConfig` class i have used `inmemory` to store client details.

At this point i do not have anything in my resource server though i do not nedd it right now . I just want to create token which i am sure it will generated via `Authorization` server.

Now when i open this url 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/fd/redirectauthorization' i got this screen.

[image]

After providing credentials

[image]

This is my custome oauth screen i am not using default oauth approval screen 
My OAuth Controller is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/oauth")
public class OauthController {

    @Autowired
    ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping("/confirm_access")
    public String confirmAccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpSession httpSession){            
        // logic
        return "oauthAccess";
    }

}
```

On Approval Controller takes me to the redirected url with some `code` value

Code for redirection

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fd")
public class RedirectController {

    @RequestMapping("/redirectauthorization")
    public String redirectauthorization(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession httpSession){

        return "authorizationcode";
    }
}
```

[image]

Now i got code appended in url using this code i try to get token using curl command but getting Bad Credential error or Unauthorized error(401) as shown in below picture

[image]

```
curl acme:acmesecret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=WeIYSm'
```

Can anyone guide me to generate oauth token

Answer (score 0):

Your curl should look more like this:

curl acme:acmesecret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d